# Helical antenna on PCB connected on ground?

Tags: pcb-design, ground-plane, pcb-antenna

I purchased the wireless bell that works on 433 MHz and would like to have an antenna with more gain in order to receive the signal a little bit far.
When I opened the device I found the helical antenna as shown on the picture.
The issue is that the place where this helical antenna is sold on the PCB is connected to the ground!
Shouldn't be, correct?
You can see the bottom of PCB where the helical antenna is solded. This is connected to the top metal part and all the ground on the PCB.

Please, any information about this?
For me seems strange the way is designed.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The antenna doesn't appear to be connected to GND. The trace from the pad runs to the capacitor/resistor matching network.

I've highlighted the traces in red below. As you can see the antenna goes to the network. The GND trace will be the one at the bottom.

[image: PCB with traces highlighted]

Comment: I used a multimeter to check the connections - that's why I commented about being connected to the ground.

Comment: @FabioLuzoAlves one of those components may measure as a low impedance

Comment: I see. Can be this. Anyway, I cannot see the ground plane separated from the antenna signal itself - the bottom and the top part where it's solded is the same.